# Why doesn't div align text to the top of containing div when sibling div's height is greater due to content?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs nested inside another div. Both child divs are of the same width, but one div contains more lines then the other div and as a result, one div does not align it's content text to the top of the div. I have tried using `vertical-align: top` and that hasn't worked.

```css
    .footer {
      width: 600px;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .footer > .agency,
    .footer > .vendor {
      width: 297px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .footer > .agency > .details,
    .footer > .vendor > .details {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
```

```html
       <div class="footer">
         <div class="agency">
            <div class="title"><b>Agency</b></div>
            <div class="details">
               <div class="name">Name</div>
               <div class="address1">address</div>
               <div class="address2"></div>
               <div class="city-state-zip">City, ST 12345</div>               
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vendor">
            <div class="title"><b>Vendor</b></div>
            <div class="details">
               <div class="name">Anonymous</div>
            </div>            
         </div>         
      </div>
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1bfwne2y/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. http://codepen.io/nwalton3/pen/bEdpoR

Comment: I suspect something else is causing the issue. Your markup doesn't fully match with the screenshot. Perhaps `vendor.title` has some top padding? Maybe you're looking at the site in IE6? We need more info.

Comment: @Moob man yea... Cud be IE6...

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I created a jsfiddle without all of my surrounding and it is working properly. There must be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `display: inline-block`, it aligns to the `baseline` and not to the middle, or top. So you need to use `vertical-align: top` to align the top of all the `inline-block` elements on the same line:

```
.footer > .agency,
.footer > .vendor {
  width: 297px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

You should give the `vertical-align: top` for the `inline-block`'s parent too.

Comment: @MusicalShore You didn't make me finish. Check now... Did you add `vertical-align: top;` to the parent as well?

Comment: @MusicalShore Copy the above code and tell me if it works.

Comment: @MusicalShore **You did not add the code!!!** Add this man! **`.footer {
  vertical-align: top;
}`**

Comment: That doesn't work, adding `vertical-align: top` to the footer.

Comment: Can you please create a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer {
      width: 300px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      border:1px solid;
    }
.footer > .agency,
.footer > .vendor {
      width: 297px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
.footer > .agency > .details,
.footer > .vendor > .details {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="footer">
         <div class="agency">
            <div class="title"><b>Agency</b></div>
            <div class="details">
               <div class="name">Name</div>
               <div class="address1">address</div>
               <div class="address2"></div>
               <div class="city-state-zip">City, ST 12345</div> 
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="vendor">
            <div class="title"><b>Vendor</b></div>
            <div class="details">
               <div class="name">Anonymous</div>
            </div>            
         </div>         
      </div>
```